# How does the automatically created connected app works when I use workbench?

Tags: connected-apps, oauth

I've read [this article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14012/how-is-it-that-some-oauth-authenticated-apps-dont-require-an-org-to-create-a-co) but I'm still confused about what happens when I approved the access from workbench.

The connected app "Workbench" seems automatically created in my org when I approve the access from workbench.

- Who did create this connected app? And
- what is the role of this connected app?
- When workbench wants to access the resource in my org, does the connected app in my org provide client id and client secret (but they're hidden because of managed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [my answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/122479/20721). It is described in [winter 14 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_forcecom_security_sfdc_pkgs.htm) that **Salesforce installs some of these apps through an automated process.**

Connected apps are used to **access/modify data in your org through APIs**. It all depends how much access is provided in connected app.

> A "Connected App" is an application that can connect to salesforce.com
>   over Identity and Data APIs.

For example workbench has following access in your org:

[image]

Basically you can create a connected app in your org and can distribute it through manage package, so wherever this package would be installed you would have relevant access of the data of that org and as connected app was created in your packaging org you can use the client Id and secret of the app.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, Mr.Frodo. When I create a connected apps manually, it takes 2-10 minutes to reflect OAuth settings. But I can use workbench just after I approved. Why...? Is there something special for automatically created connected app?

Comment: @SergeiOmar It is not creating connected app here. It is just installing a manage package which includes that connected app. As this package only contains this connected app, it only take seconds to install.

Comment: Ah, I almost understand. Just one last thing. Workbench says it's not an official product but Salesforce Connected Apps (Managed) says it contains officially supported products. How can other 3rd party web applications be included in the managed package?

Comment: @SergeiOmar You see there is difference between Official product and officially supported product :p . It's the Salesforce who found some relevant and daily used application and created a single package for all of them. Workbench is an open source application and you can use it's code in your application as well AFAIK.

Comment: I see. Thank you for so much for your kind support!